# Latex listings package deletekeywords option not working

Tags: latex, listings

I'm using `listings` package in Latex to insert Pascal code in a document. I would like *Read* not being a keyword, so I used `deletekeywords` parameter, like this:

```
\lstset{
        language=pascal,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        backgroundcolor=\color{grisclaro},
        keywordstyle=\bf,
        commentstyle=\color{gray},
        stringstyle=\color{orange},
        breaklines=true,
        deletekeywords={Read},
        morekeywords={String,unit,uses,class,private,public}
        }
```

But *Read* is still appearing in bold like the other keywords. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: -1 because you'll probably should ask this [here instead](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=listing&s=a81b10f8-2c19-4df1-8c4b-879d3f5dac68). BTW, **read** is a keyword related to properties, why would you want it not to be colorized ?

Comment: Why should I ask in other page (even if it's related)? There are lots of question in StackOverflow about [Latex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex) and [listings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listings). I don't want to _colorize_ **read** because there is a procedure in a class called this way, and there's no property anywhere. But I don't have to answer this because it doesn't help to answer or clarify the original question. Anyways, thanks for your time.

Comment: @mclopez You will find more people knowledgable about TeX related issues on tex.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though Pascal is not case-sensitive (and so is the parsing step when parsing your listing), TeX/listings is not. The keyword was defined as `read`, not `Read`, so you must remove it with

```
deletekeywords={read}
```